# Laravel, Queue, Horizon and >10 Servers (Workers) - Creating several million jobs takes extremely long

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I need to create several 10 million jobs.

I have tried it with **for-loops** and `Bus::batch([])` and unfortunately the creation of the jobs takes longer than the processing of the jobs by the 10 servers/workers. That means the workers have to wait until the job shows up in the database (redis etc). With redis-benchmark I could learn that Redis is not the problem.

Anyway... is there a way to create jobs in BULK (not batch)? I'm just thinking of something like:

`INSERT INTO ... () VALUES (), (), (), (), ...`

Anyway, creating several million jobs in a for-loop or in batch seems to be very slow for some reason. Probably because it's always just 1 query at a time and not an "upsert".

For any help I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Writing a million records will be kind of slow at any condition. I'd recommend maximize your queue performance using several methods:

1. Create job that will create all other jobs if possible
2. Use only `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis` for your queues as redis stores data in RAM which is fastest possible.
3. [Create your jobs after response was processed already](https://divinglaravel.com/running-a-task-after-the-response-is-sent)